# generating artifacts in gitlab: Allure reporter for WDIO

Tags: javascript, automation, gitlab-ci, webdriver-io, allure

I encounter an issue at last step of my CI/CD setup using gitlab. My testing framework consists from webdriverIO + Typescript + allure-reporter. I get an error when I want to generate the report artifacts as follows:
[image]

I have 2 folders one called allure-results which is in artifacts archive, and allure-report which cannot be found. I rechecked the path, but seems should be ok.
Any idea or example regarding to allure reporter in gitlab?

Bellow I can put my config file for webdriverIO

```js
 reporters: ['spec', ['cucumberjs-json', {
        jsonFolder: 'artifacts/jsonReports',
        language: 'en'
    }],
    ['allure', {
        outputDir: 'allure-results',
        useCucumberStepReporter: true,
        disableWebdriverStepsReporting: false,
        disableWebdriverScreenshotsReporting: false,
    }]],
```

gitlab-ci.yml

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Locally works as expected. Thanks

gitlab-ci.yml

```js
cache:
    paths:
        - node_modules/

run_test_chrome:
    image: atools/chrome-headless:java11-node14-latest
    script:
        - npm install
        - npm run e2e
        - allure generate ./artifacts/allure-results
    artifacts:
        when: always
        paths:
            - artifacts/allure-report
            - artifacts/allure-results
            - allure-report
        expire_in: 1 week
    only:
    - master
```

Comment: and your gitlab-ci.yml?

Comment: I've updated the post, thanks for remark

Comment: please paste code of your `gitlab-ci.yml`, not an image

Answer (score 0):

Change your

```
allure generate ./artifacts/allure-results
```

to

```
allure generate -c ./artifacts/allure-results -o ./artifacts/allure-report
```